# Count and Remove Duplicates, leaving number of duplicates removed plus unique value (Function Key/Send Key/Calculate)

Tags: excel, vba

ive been trying to figure this out for a few days now and it is now time to turn to the coding wizards :). I have tried to comment the code below as much as possible to make it clear the procedure i am trying to achieve, but i will try to explain.

Essentially i have a document that will contain data in columns "A" and "B" which also correspond to each other, for example in column A i could have "Fiesta" and in column B "Ford", all down the columns would be this type of information where multiple duplicates can occur. i want to number the numerical value of the duplicates in column "C" and to remove the duplicates, leaving me with the unique entries and the number of duplicates plus the one remaining.

I have looked in lots of places for different methods on how to do this and below i have inserted the code which i created and is almost working perfectly. However im having issues with extracting the value out of the formula before removing the duplicates because obviously the value will change with the countif statement after i have removed the duplicate values.

Example of Spreadsheet:

("A" and "B" should be other way around)

Initial Entry- https://gyazo.com/2813c54391564af6346132e1d27f32a5
Desired Output -https://gyazo.com/9933e4f5e5278e15d038ff7df55617ec

```
Sub Marco()
Dim x As Integer
'Used to remove unwanted characters from text within cells
Cells.Replace What:="'", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:= _
    xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False
Cells.Replace What:=",", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:= _
    xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False


'Counts rows within column "A"
  NumRows = Range("A1", Range("A1").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count

'Selects Cell "C1" to process the proceeding loop
  Range("C1").Select

  'A loop that carries out given functions for all cells with data.
  For x = 1 To NumRows

  'Creates a count if statement for all duplicate information
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=COUNTIF(C1,RC1)"
    ActiveCell.Select

    'Change the forumla for countif to the value
    Application.SendKeys "{F2}", True
    Application.SendKeys "{F9}", True

    'Moves down to next cell in column
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
  Next
'Removes all duplicate values only leaving require information
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$C$500").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1, 2), Header _
    :=xlYes

End Sub
```

If you require anymore information just comment below :). Thank you in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

You can try copy and paste values before remove duplicates:

1 - in loop:

change:

```
Application.SendKeys "{F2}", True
Application.SendKeys "{F9}", True
```

to:

```
With ActiveCell
.Copy
.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
End With
```

2 - or after loop copy and paste all column:

```
Columns("C:C").Select
Selection.Copy
Selection.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
```

Its should work

Edit:

change your formula countif to:

`ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=COUNTIFS(C1,RC1,C2,RC2)"`

change parameters in `.RemoveDuplicates` to:

`Columns:=Array(1, 2), Header:=xlNo` (No header)

now OK?

Comment: I tried altering the code, but it still outputs the formula which changes the number.

Answer (score 0):

Managed to figure it out.

```
Sub Marco()
Dim x As Integer
Dim sh As Worksheet
'Used to remove unwanted characters from text within cells
Cells.Replace What:="'", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:= _
    xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False
Cells.Replace What:=",", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:= _
    xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False


'Counts rows within column "A"
  NumRows = Range("A1", Range("A1").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count

'Selects Cell "C1" to process the proceeding loop
  Range("C1").Select

  'A loop that carries out given functions for all cells with data.
  For x = 1 To NumRows

  'Creates a count if statement for all duplicate information
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=COUNTIF(C1,RC1)"
    ActiveCell.Select

    'Moves down to next cell in column
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
  Next
'Changes all forumlas to values
For Each sh In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    With sh.UsedRange
        .Value = .Value
    End With
Next sh

'Removes all duplicate values only leaving require information
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$C$500").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1, 2), Header _
    :=xlYes
Range("A1").Select
End Sub
```

Parts added:

```
For Each sh In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    With sh.UsedRange
        .Value = .Value
    End With
Next sh
```